# What happened to Michayhu?

Tags: melachim-kings-book-of, prophecies, book-of-chronicles

As described in [Ⅰ *M'lachim* 22](http://chabad.org/15906) and [Ⅱ *Divre Hayamim* 18](http://chabad.org/16567), King *Ach'av* of *Yisrael* (the northern kingdom) suggested that King *Y'hoshafat* of *Y'huda* join him in battle against *Aram*. A number of *Baal*-prophets prophesied that they would be successful and should go to battle, but *Y'hoshafat* wanted to know what a *Hashem*-prophet had to say. So they fetched *Michayhu ben Yimla*. He prophesied that they would be unsuccessful in the battle against *Aram* (if they went) and should not go. *Ach'av* heard that but was certain of victory, so he ordered *Michayhu* jailed until such time as he (*Ach'av*) would return from battle victorious.

*Ach'av* died in battle.

What then happened to *Michayhu*: Was he released from prison? Killed? Allowed to rot there? And why? And, if he was released or killed, under what circumstances and when?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/121855

Answer (score 1):

Admittedly not a great or informative answer, but [מחזור ויטרי](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=33694&pgnum=528) has one of those "lineage of torah" lists where he puts Michayhu as the "student" of Elisha and the teacher of Ovadia.   Given that Elisha lived to see 3-4 kings after Ach'av and Ovadia seems to have at least prophesied about attacks from Edom that happened during Jehoram (a king of Judah during Achav's son/grandson), one would presume Simhah of Vitri held that Michayhu survived.

Comment: How does prophesying about later attacks mean he lived later?

Comment: Strictly speaking it doesn't.   The timing of when Ovadia lived is a bit complicated as his whole prophecy is a single castigation of Edom -- warning them not to attack while Israel is in trouble.   Based on this we can probably claim that the warning was about of two historical points, the earlier of which happened after Achav.   It obviously takes the assumption that Ovadia is speaking in "real time" (i.e. warning Edom right then) to place him.

Comment: Probably worth noting that there is also a mention of "Ovadia" during the reign of Achav and that in Sanhedrin they do associate him with the prophet of the same name.

Answer (score 0):

The possuk in Melachim 1'22'36' depicting Achav's death reads as follows.

ויעבר 'הרנה' במחנה כבא השמש לאמר איש אל עירו ואיש אל ארצו

Meaning that the joyous news floated around the jewish camp saying all are free to go back to their cities as the war and the troubles are over.

Perhaps the prisoners as well were included in that announcement.

The reasoning;as we find by Nebuchadnetsar's death that the possuk there Yeshayah 14'7' also says upon his death,'נחה שקטה כל הארץ פצחו 'רנה saying that there too news of his death was a joyous occasion,and later the possuk reads 14'19' ואתה השלכת מקברך כנצר נתעב meaning that they pulled him out of his burial plot dragging him all around the city to show to all that his gezairos are off.

This is as we see in the last pessukim in melachim that Yehoyochin was led out of jail being that Nebuchadnetsar and all that comes with him is foiled.

It follows then perhaps that the Rina brought out in both of their deaths had similar tolls freeing 'all',of his rule,dictates and jailings.

Answer (score -1):

There is a critical scholarly theory that Michayhu and the prophet Micha (who lived much later) are one and the same person. [This theory](http://jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/10777-micah-book-of) stems from similarities in the language of their prophecies. Assuming this theory is correct there is not consensus as to how he died. However

> Pseudo-Epiphanius ("Opera," ii. 245) ... states that Micah, for his inauspicious prophecy, was killed by order of Ahab through being thrown from a precipice, and was buried at Morathi (Maroth?; Mic. i. 12), near the cemetery of Enakim. According to "Gelilot Ereẓ Yisrael" (quoted in "Seder ha-Dorot," i. 118, Warsaw, 1889), Micah was buried in Chesil, a town in southern Judah (Josh. xv. 30). [source](http://jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/10776-micah)

Comment: "There is a critical scholarly theory that Michayhu and the prophet Micha (who lived much later) are one and the same person." So these scholars think he had a very long life?

Comment: @msh210 I wouldn't want to speculate