# Why didn't Yehoshafat intervene?

Tags: malchut-royalty, navi-prophets, melachim-kings-book-of, book-of-chronicles

In [Melachim 1:22:7-28](https://www.sefaria.org.il/I_Kings.22.7-28?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi) and in [Divrei Hayamim 2:18:6-27](https://www.sefaria.org.il/II_Chronicles.18.6-27?lang=bi) we're told that Yehoshafat joined his father-in-law Achav to do battle with Aram. Unsure of the future, they decide to ask prophets what will be the outcome of the battle. Achav assembles 400 false prophets and they all say that Am Yisrael (the two kingdoms) will be victorious. Still doubtful, Yehoshafat requests a prophet of Hashem be brought. Michayhu ben Yimlah is brought, and he warns Achav that he'll fall in battle. Angry, Achav sends Michayhu to jail.

I was wondering why Yehoshafat didn't do anything for Michayhu. After all, Michayhu was brought to the camp at his own behest, so it's kind of his fault that Michayhu, at that time at least, said things that Achav didn't like. Moreover, Yehoshafat was in general a good and righteous king. One would expect he'd do his best to defend a prophet of Hashem.

Comment: Perhaps he was afraid of what achav would do to him. You don't get the sense yehoshafat was the dominant figure there

Comment: @DoubleAA Yeah, I thought about that, but it's not as though Yehoshafat was a useless weakling. He made several important reforms in Judea. I'm not entirely sure what Achav *could* have done to him - they were relatives and were clearly attempting to find a way to somehow join the two kingdoms, at least partially. Each side offers the other something: Achav wed his daughter to Yehoshafat, and the two kingdoms were at peace with each other. Yehoshafat came to help Achav for his part, and Achav, hypothetically, should have returned the favor.

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/57154

Comment: @DoubleAA Why should he intervene. Achav was doing the right thing only keeping him in jail till he came back. We dont know how bad this jail was. Why should he let him go. If he was wrong shouldnt he deserve death.

Comment: @interested the text says that he was to be fed לחם צר ומים לחץ - that's far from quality food.

Comment: :@Harel13 OK But remember he had prophesied his death. Not something one likes to hear. I doubt that Yehoshafat could save him from that.

Comment: @interested that's not quite what he said: he said *if* you go to battle, you'll lose and die. Furthermore, Eliyahu already told Achav he'll be punished for various things. It's not like hearing bad things from prophets was new to him.

Comment: It's worth noting that Yehoshafat was punished for joining with Achav. That might include this within it.