# Is anything else known about King Ahab's sister, who according to the medrish was a Judean queen?

Tags: women, midrash, malchut-royalty, melachim-kings-book-of

In [I Kings 16:22](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Kings.16.22?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=he), Rashi quotes *Seder Olam* that King Asa, the righteous king of Judea, married his son Yehoshafat (also a good guy) to the daughter of the not-so-righteous King Omri of North Israel.

Of course Omri is succeeded by his son Achav (Ahab), a total no-goodnick.

So that means as Achav is busy killing out the prophets of Hashem to make way for more Baal worship, his sister is sitting in a palace in Jerusalem where things are going okay ... must have been a complicated dynamic! (I'd ask why Asa and his son thought this marriage was a good idea, but perhaps that's before Omri made bad decisions.) Do we know anything else about this lady?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/71839/759

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/121855/why-didnt-yehoshafat-intervene

Comment: According to [this](https://jbqnew.jewishbible.org/assets/Uploads/421/JBQ_421_3_kleinathaliah.pdf) essay by @RebChaimHaQoton, some emend Seder Olam to read "Asa married his grandson Jehoram to a daughter of Omri".

Answer (score 1):

The only additional source that I came across other than the [Seder Olam Rabbah 17](https://www.sefaria.org/Seder_Olam_Rabbah.17.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) that Rashi quotes from, is the [Tosefta Sotah 12](https://www.sefaria.org/Tosefta_Sotah.12.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) where it writes:

> כיון שהשיא אסא מלך יהודה את בתו של עמרי מלך ישראל ליהושפט בנו לאשה נגזרה על מלכות דוד שתכלה עם בית אחאב שנאמר (דברי הימים ב כ״ב:ז׳) ומאלהים היתה תבוסת אחזיהו וגו' ונפלו שניהם בו ביום זה עם זה
>
> When Asa King of Judah married the daughter of Omri king of Israel as a wife for Yehoshafat his son, it was decreed that the a king of the House of Dovid would perish (lit. end) together with the house of Achav. As it says ([Divrei HaYamim II 22:7](https://www.sefaria.org/II_Chronicles.22.7?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) "G-d caused the downfall of Achaziah etc." - (Therefore) both of them (i.e. Achaziah king of Israel and Yehoshafat king of Judah) fell on the same day.